# How can I dump a list of the contents of a *.tgz to a text file without extracting it (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, tar, gnome-terminal

I have a huge (100+GB) *.tgz archive and I would like to dump its contents (paths and filenames) into a text file. I know how to list them in the terminal:

```
tar -ztvf my-data.tar.gz
```

...but I can't figure out how to get the list into a text file.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use something like:
`tar -ztvf my-data.tar.gz > fileswithin.txt`